# Solving differential equation in R - deSolve

Tags: r, ode, differential-equations

I have an equation as below;

```
dN/dt = N(t)G(t)
```

`G(t)` is given by the equation: `dG/dt = a * G`
 How do I solve this in R, using ode function from deSolve package?

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and show (in code) what you have already tried. That way you can help others to help you!

Answer (score 2):

As dario already mentioned, the question lacks some details. Nevertheless, let's try an answer. If we assume that `a < 0`, the model looks like the ode formulation of Gompertz growth:

```
dN/dt = N * G
dG/dt = a * G
```

This can then be solved as:

```
library(deSolve)

model <- function(t, y, p) {
  with(as.list(c(y, p)), {
    dN <-  N * G
    dG <-  a * G
    list(c(dN, dG))
  })
}

y      <- c(N = 1, G = 1)
parms  <- c(a = -0.1)
times  <- seq(0, 100)
out <- ode(y, times, model, parms)
plot(out)
```